# Android app - Send gamepad key through keyboard input

Tags: java, android, input, keyboard, gamepad

I am developing a keyboard app for Android in Java and I want to be able to send inputs as if my application was a virtual game controller.

Example:

The inputs I want to send are among the following default buttons (DPAD_UP, BUTTON_A, etc)

[image: Controller buttons]

Image source: https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input

I see a lot of resources regarding Event listeners and how to handle gamepad or key inputs (as if I was a game receiving inputs), but I haven't found anything on the "server side", on how to actually send these inputs from one app (my keyboard) to another (the game).

I have already registered my app as a keyboard app, and I am able to send normal key inputs (such as letters) to compose a text. To to that I am overriding the function onKey() from KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.

Sources: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener#onKey(int,%20int[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener#onKey(int,%20int%5B%5D))

https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-custom-keyboard-android-832362/

```
@Override
 public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
     InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
     if (inputConnection != null) {
         switch(primaryCode) {
             case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
                 CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
 
                 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                     inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                 } else {
                     inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
                 }
             case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                 caps = !caps;
                 keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                 keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                 break;
             case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                 inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
 
                 break;
             default :
                 char code = (char) primaryCode;
                 if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                     code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                 }
                 inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
 
         }
     }
 
 }
```

However, I don't see how this could help me send the gamepad Keycodes.

So my question is: what is the correct way to send the game controller keypresses from my app to another app (the game)? I want to be able to press a virtual button on my app (emulating a BUTTON_A [keycode 96] for example), and send this key input to the game.

Important: my app cannot have root privileges or be signed as a system app. So that is why I am trying the keyboard approach, so I can be registered as a virtual keyboard on the device that I want to control and then be able to send key inputs from inside my app to another app running on the same device (the game that supports a game controller).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will your keyboard even be visible when the game is being played?

Comment: No, it would run on the background and my server will send the game inputs through the backend

Comment: AFAIK, input method editors (keyboards) only have an effect when they are visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile this as a native binary and run it through adb it works (and doesn't require root). Hopefully this can be a starting point for you:

to compile and run:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a infile.c  -o helloworld

adb push helloworld /data/local/tmp

adb shell
```

*inside the shell run:*

```
/data/local/tmp/helloworld
```

*in a seperate terminal run `adb shell getevents` and you will see the "A" controller key being pressed which means the script is working

```
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <linux/uinput.h>
    
    void emit(int fd, int type, int code, int val)
    {
       struct input_event ie;
    
       ie.type = type;
       ie.code = code;
       ie.value = val;
       /* timestamp values below are ignored */
       ie.time.tv_sec = 0;
       ie.time.tv_usec = 0;
    
       write(fd, &ie, sizeof(ie));
    }
    
    int main(void)
    {
       struct uinput_setup usetup;
    
       int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    
    
       /*
        * The ioctls below will enable the device that is about to be
        * created, to pass key events, in this case the space key.
        */
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_SPACE);
        ioctl (fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, REL_X);
        ioctl (fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, REL_Y);
        ioctl (fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, REL_Z);
        ioctl (fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, REL_RZ);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_A);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_B);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_X);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_Y);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TL);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TR);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_THUMBL);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_THUMBR);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_UP);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_RIGHT);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_DOWN);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_LEFT);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_SELECT);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_START);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MODE);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY1); //dpad left
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY2); //dpad right
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY3); //dpad up
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY4); //dpad down
    
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_X);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_Y);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_Z); //LT
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_RX);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_RY);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_RZ);   //RT
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_HAT0Y);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_HAT0X);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_UP);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_UP+1);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_UP+2);
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_DPAD_UP+3);
        memset(&usetup, 0, sizeof(usetup));
        usetup.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
        usetup.id.vendor = 0x1234; /* sample vendor */
        usetup.id.product = 0x5678; /* sample product */
        strcpy(usetup.name, "Example device");
    
        ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_SETUP, &usetup);
        ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);
    
    
    
       /*
        * On UI_DEV_CREATE the kernel will create the device node for this
        * device. We are inserting a pause here so that userspace has time
        * to detect, initialize the new device, and can start listening to
        * the event, otherwise it will not notice the event we are about
        * to send. This pause is only needed in our example code!
        */
       sleep(1);
    
    
       /*
        * Give userspace some time to read the events before we destroy the
        * device with UI_DEV_DESTOY.
        */
       sleep(1);
    
       while(1){
          //Just keep pressing the A key
          sleep(1);
    
          /* Key press, report the event, send key release, and report again */
          emit(fd, EV_KEY, BTN_A+(1), 1);
          emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
          emit(fd, EV_KEY, BTN_A+(1), 0);
          emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
       }
    
    
       //ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
       close(fd);
    
       return 0;
    }
```